# How to set two series for one category in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I am facing this problem in highcharts that i have two series for one category . then how can i set these two series for the same category . for example , please see image . 
i have category (from JAN 13 , to Mar 15) , and i have a series which is showing in light blue color(for first series) for session planning . and i want to add an another series for the same category (from JAN 13 , to Mar 15) which is its progress series (in dark blue color ), Then how can i set this ? i am new in highcharts .[image]

Comment: You can use stacked columns or bars. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/spwc97x0/

Comment: series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }]

Comment: i want this john and jane on same

Comment: I don't know any method to do so. Can't help here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `columnRange` serie and disable `grouping` property.

```
        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                grouping:false
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            data: [
                [-9.7, 9.4],
                [-8.7, 6.5],
                [-3.5, 9.4]
            ]
        },{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            data: [
                [9.4, 12],
                [6.5, 8],
                [9.4,10]
            ]
        }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z1pr35mz/

Comment: series: [{
            name: 'dates',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1), Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5)]
               
            ]
        },{
            name: 'dates',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1), 10]
                
            ]
        }]

Comment: i want to plot this series .. here 10 is the progress that plotted on the first series